# ¿como hacer una busqueda pasando parametros con React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

es una api de noticias pero no se como hacer que el buscador funcione es decir quiero hacer `this.props.history.push("/:query")` pero no esta funcionando, este es mi codigo jsx.

las rutas

```js
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <Header />
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/categorias/:category" exact component={Category} />
            <Route path="/busqueda/:query" component={Busqueda} />
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

este es el componente busqueda

```js
class Busqueda extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ data: event.target.value });
    this.props.history.push("/:query");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <form className="text">
            <input
              className="text__input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ingresa un texto"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button className="text__button">buscar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

y este el heder donde paso el componente busqueda

```js
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppBar position="static">
        <StyledToolbar style={{ backgroundColor: "#f50057" }}>
          <Typography variant="h6">News Feeds</Typography>
          <Busqueda />
        </StyledToolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}
```

Me da error dice que el metodo push del `this.props.history.push("/:query")` esta indefinido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta exportar el componente `Busqueda` utilizando el metodo [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md), este le agregara el metodo `history()` al `this.props` de tu componente:

Busqueda.jsx:

```
//...
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Busqueda extends Component {
  //...
}

export default withRouter(Busqueda);
```

Comment: ahora me aparece el parametro localhost:3000/:query pero este "query" no agarra el valor de lo que escribo en el input, pero gracias es un paso mas a resolverlo ;)

Comment: sabes lo raro es que escribo en el buscador una palabra y me devuelve el componente buscador y no el arreglo de busquedas :(